# How to get VBScript to click on input class onclick element on Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, button, vbscript, getelementbyid

How can I get my VBScript code to click on an Input Class Onclick button on a website?

**Source Code:**

```
<input class="bzeAccountOverviewTile cuiButtonFont cuiButtonFix cuiButton" onclick="bzeStopPropagation(event);bzeMainWorkbench.fillSubmitRowClickForm('a2rTilePostForm', {'accountId':'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA','altCashAccId':'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB','goToScreen':'TR_CashPostings','navitemid':'AccountPg'}, true);" 
type="button" value="Transactions">
```

**VBScript Code**

```
For Each Button In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
 If InStr(Button.getAttribute("onclick"), "bzeStopPropagation(event);bzeMainWorkbench.fillSubmitRowClickForm('a2rTilePostForm', {'accountId':'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA','altCashAccId':'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB','goToScreen':'TR_CashPostings','navitemid':'AccountPg'}, true);") Then
 Button.Click
Exit For
End If
Next
```

I have also tried

```
IE.Document.getElementsByName("bzeAccountOverviewTile cuiButtonFont cuiButtonFix cuiButton")(0).click
```

As well as

```
Set oInputs = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each elm In oInputs
  If elm.Value = "Transactions" Then
    elm.Click
    Exit For
  End If 
Next
```

Although I am getting no errors, the code is also not clicking on the desired button.

Comment: are you receiving any errors?

Comment: There are no errors but it is also not clicking on anything

Comment: have you determined if you are able to even find the button? also, there may be other ways to achieve the end result, if you care to share what clicking the button does for you...

Comment: Clicking the buttons directs me to a detailed report of a certain account, hence the accountID in the source code. In terms of finding the button, what do you mean? I can see and click the button on my browser.

Comment: Sorry, I just meant does the code actually find the button, using `InStr(Button...`. Also, if the site accepts GET requests, you may be able to add the `accountID` to the URL and bypass the button click.

Comment: @WhiteHat I have posted an updated source code, if you look at the type it is "button"

Comment: try `IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")` instead of `IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")` -- can you share the web site?

Comment: Website: https://ebanking-ch2.ubs.com/workbench/WorkbenchOpenAction.do?login&&NavLB_EBCH=1442429830

Comment: `IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")` did not work